# Two different settings.xml on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a scenario where changes have to be made in settings.xml file,i.e., adding a repository of another service not under our project, so that we can pull libraries of that repository to our project. So, under our Organization's Jenkins server, we have 4-5 applications, all following same settings.xml while running builds, and that cannot be modified. So, is there a way where we can add a different settings.xml file, with our changes to be accepted by only one service pipeline of our application.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `settings.xml`  on the command line with the parameter `-s`, something like:

```
mvn clean deploy -s my-own-settings.xml
```